# Changing the area path on the backlogs in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, scrum, backlog

We're changing the area path on our user stories from MyApp\OldPath\MyTeam to MyApp\NewPath\MyTeam.  It's pretty easy to change the stories.  I'm trying to figure out how to do it for my backlog.  I'm not seeing a way to do it.  I'm reading some stuff that it appears that I need to export it, edit it with the witadmin tool, and reimport it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the way to do it is to go to the Work tab in the Control Panel and add the area there.

You can optionally remove the old area path.  I left it since there are some old stories out there with the old path.